Bone in armature not copying transforms
I have a mixamo rig and mixamo control rig that can switch between IK and FK for arms and legs. I have animated extensively with the rig and its been fine, but I am having a problem in both the original blend file and the file that it has been imported into where one of the bones will not follow the transforms of the IK armature.

I have tried turning off IK constraints and using a simple rotation constraint.
I have tried putting on a damped track constraint to follow the bone (just to see).
I have checked all bones for locked IKs
I have tried turning off the constraints and putting on other transform constraints.
I have checked bone rolls, and cleared all rotation and other transforms. It should matter anyway since the the constraints are set to "replace".
I have even set up an IK in FK mode, and I can see the control rig for FK working properly, but the bone in question STILL will not copy the transforms of even the FK.

I am completely stumped. It's been working fine and then suddenly it isn't. The IK-FK relationship is working fine on the other arm. Note the picture below. The control object is for IK, and the bones for the IK rig are working as expected, but the main bone just refuses to copy the transforms for the IK bone.

If I try changing the target/owner relationship, or the blend mode, the arm moves but it still does not change with the transformations of the owner bone.
Does anybody have any ideas as to how I might resolve this?

This has been driving me crazy - does no one else experience this? Is there anywhere else I might go for some more help? Basically it seems to be an issue with a Mixamo Rig where the IK controller is using a copy location transform. What's weird is that the rig with the transform is working properly, but the rig that is supposed to follow that rig is not. Trying to solve this has cost me days/weeks in time and working around it is a major headache.
